# ember-rails Ember Inspector does not detect app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ember.js, ember-rails

I'm using rails 4 with:

```
gem 'ember-rails'
gem 'ember-source', '2.0'
```

`ember-rails` is at version 0.19 in my `Gemfile.lock`. I'm very new to ember (and javascript frameworks in general) and I'm following [this tutorial](http://emberbites.com/1-adding-ember-to-a-rails-app/). It was written in April 2014 so I think it might be out of date but it's the most recent guide to ember-rails with rails 4 that I can find.

Most of the setup was generated by running `rails generate ember:bootstrap` and `application.js.coffee` looks like this:

```
#= require jquery
#= require jquery_ujs
#= require ember
#= require ember-data
#= require active-model-adapter
#= require_self
#= require api

# for more details see: http://emberjs.com/guides/application/
window.Api = Ember.Application.create()
```

Also api.js.coffee looks like this:

```
#= require_tree ./adapters
#= require_tree ./mixins
#= require_tree ./models
#= require_tree ./controllers
#= require_tree ./views
#= require_tree ./helpers
#= require_tree ./components
#= require_tree ./templates
#= require_tree ./routes
#= require ./router
#= require_self
```

My problem is that when I click on the ember inspector in Chrome's developer tools, I get the 'Ember application not detected' message. The two coffeescript files I referenced above are the only two files the tutorial has talked about so far so I think the error might be with one of them. If you need more information please let me know. When I run the rails server then try to access the Ember Inspector this is what I see in the console:

> DEBUG: -------------------------------
>
> DEBUG: Ember      : 2.0.0
>
> DEBUG: Ember Data : 2.1.0
>
> DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.11.3
>
> DEBUG: -------------------------------
>
> `Uncaught TypeError: this.validateFullName is not a function`
>
> Ember Inspector Active

Comment: I would check out this tutorial for rails and ember. It's pretty well done. http://ember.vicramon.com/

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you don't have a template defined for ember to render.

By default it looks at the application template. From the tutorial I pointed out above. Once you get that implemented you should be able to see the ember inspector.

```
// app/assets/javascripts/templates/application.js.emblem
h1 Hello World
outlet
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't solve the problem. I did have a template but it had the .hbs extension instead of .js.emblem - I've renamed the file but I still can't see Ember Inspector. I'll follow the tutorial you linked to later and see if that works instead. There's probably a few steps I'm missing.